# Improving TS-vector Query with JOIN statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, indexing, full-text-search

Hi all nice people out there. 
on Postgres (Version 9.6) I have 3 tables

1. **app_complaint_main** (8 Million records)

| PK | company_id | consumer_complaint_narrative_id | complaint_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 44 | 55 |

2. **app_company** (6 K records)

| PK | company_name |
| --- | --- |
| 33 | 'ACME' |

3. **app_consumer_complaint_narrative** (2.5 Million records)

| PK | text | fts_document(tsvector) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | "Hello World" | lexems |

the text search is absolutely amazing  - it went from 7 Min. to 100 MS, 
however when it comes to cases where I need to find the companies that have complaints with the desired text + a list of the complaint_ids that contained this word it got messy...
because it must loop through the main table for both company_id and complaint_id relations
(and yes, I did use an Index for the consumer_complaint_narrative_id forign_key)

**Disclaimer** - I recently found out that the app_consumer_complaint_narrative table contains duplicate texts which, in turn, caused duplicate lexems.
but when I tried to use DISTINCT on the search it took a long time(the GIN Index is not designed for comparing a TSvector filed to another).
so I'm facing 2 issues:

- duplicate lexems to run on
- 2 join statements to workaround
  attached is the **Query** I'm currently using

  ```
   SELECT a.company_name ,a.ids
  from(
  SELECT ac.company_name, ARRAY_AGG(distinct  acm.complaint_id) ids
  FROM public.app_complaint_main acm
   join public.app_company ac 
  on acm.company_id = ac.id
  join public.app_consumer_complaint_narrative accn
  on acm.consumer_complaint_narrative_id = accn.id
   WHERE fts_document @@ to_tsquery('english','fish')
   group by ac.company_name
  )a
  ```

**analysis** :  
#   Node    Timings Rows    Loops
Exclusive   Inclusive   Rows X  Actual  Plan

1. Aggregate (cost=83408.52..87419.85 rows=6726 width=59) (actual=104.14..107.721 rows=163 loops=1)    0.344 ms    107.721 ms  ↑ 41.27 163 6726    1
2. Gather Merge (cost=83408.52..87174.12 rows=32332 width=31) (actual=104.113..107.378 rows=756 loops=1)   -113.434 ms 107.378 ms  ↑ 42.77 756 32332   1
3. Sort (cost=82408.5..82442.18 rows=13472 width=31) (actual=73.585..73.604 rows=252 loops=3)  1.479 ms    220.812 ms  ↑ 53.47 252 13472   3
4. Hash Inner Join (cost=355.79..81484.48 rows=13472 width=31) (actual=5.113..73.111 rows=252 loops=3)
   Hash Cond: (acm.company_id = ac.id)
   1.625 ms    219.334 ms  ↑ 53.47 252 13472   3
5. Nested Loop Inner Join (cost=134.46..81227.76 rows=13472 width=8) (actual=1.314..68.908 rows=252 loops=3)   1.648 ms    206.724 ms  ↑ 53.47 252 13472   3
6. Bitmap Heap Scan on app_consumer_complaint_narrative as accn (cost=134.02..45406.89 rows=5270 width=4) (actual=1.265..45.282 rows=268 loops=3)
   Recheck Cond: (fts_document @@ '''fish'''::tsquery)
   Heap Blocks: exact=342
   132.793 ms  135.846 ms  ↑ 19.67 268 5270    3
7. Bitmap Index Scan using fts_idx (cost=0..130.86 rows=12648 width=0) (actual=3.053..3.053 rows=805 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (fts_document @@ '''fish'''::tsquery)
   3.053 ms    3.053 ms    ↑ 15.72 805 12648   1
8. Index Scan using app_complaint_main_consumer_complaint_narrative_id_idx on app_complaint_main as acm (cost=0.43..6.79 rows=1 width=12) (actual=0.085..0.086 rows=1 loops=805)
   Index Cond: (consumer_complaint_narrative_id = accn.id)
   69.23 ms    69.23 ms    ↑ 1 1   1   805
9. Hash (cost=137.26..137.26 rows=6726 width=31) (actual=3.662..3.662 rows=6736 loops=3)
   Buckets: 8192 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 489 kB
   5.248 ms    10.986 ms   ↓ 1.01  6736    6726    3
10. Seq Scan on app_company as ac (cost=0..137.26 rows=6726 width=31) (actual=0.02..1.913 rows=6736 loops=3)    5.739 ms    5.739 ms    ↓ 1.01  6736    6726    3

Comment: can I ask for help from the Postgres justice league?
@Erwin Brandstetter?

Comment: , @a_horse_with_no_name?